# Check if an object exists in JSON

Tags: android, json, deserialization, gson

I need to know if an object exists in a JSON string and do different things depending on the existence of that object. If it doesn't exist, I want omit the object because it throws NullPonterException. I've tried using **if** but no success... Can someone tell me how can I check the existence of an object?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show code, but as a starter - have you tried using the opt-methods, e.g. `JSONObject#optJSONObject(String)` or similar? They return `null` if the mapping does not exist instead of an exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
String jsonString = yourJsonString;
String nameOfObjectInQuestion = "yourObjectInQuestion";
JSONObject json = null;
JSONObject objectInQuestion = null;
try { 
    json = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
    objectInQuestion = json.getJSONObject(nameOfObjectInQuestion);
} 
catch (JSONException ignored) {}

if (objectInQuestion == null) {
    // Stomp your feet
}
else {
    // Clap your hands
}
```

Comment: Philips It works like a charm! My problem is solved but... is there any way to get the same result but doing it with the GSON library? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use isNull() function on JSONObjects.

*"boolean    isNull(String name)
Returns true if this object has no mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.*"

```
JSONObject contact = venueitem.getJSONObject("contact");

if (contact.isNull("formattedPhone") == false)
    venue.phone = contact.getString("formattedPhone");
else
    {
    ...
    }
```

Source :
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)

Comment: The following line will cause an exception.

JSONObject contact = venueitem.getJSONObject("contact");

Answer (score 3):

Use JSONObject.has(String).

```
 JSONObject MyObject = null;
 if(JSONObject.has("ObjectName")){
        MyObject = JSONObject.getJSONObject("ObjectName");
 }

 if(MyObject != null){
  // do stuff
 }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Or.. more concise...

```
myJSONObject.isNull("myfield")?"":myJSONObject.getString("myfield")
```