# JSON with different structure - Android

Tags: android, json

I'm getting JSON with different structure. One is with gallery, but other not.

First JSON: (without gallery)

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "title": "titletitle",
  "fulltext": "texttext",
  "related_articles":[
    {
      "id": "12346",
      "title": "titletitle",
      "image_name": "www.example.com/img1.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "12347",
      "title": "titletitle",
      "image_name": "www.example.com/img2.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Second JSON (with gallery)

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "title": "titletitle",
  "fulltext": "texttext",
  "gallery": [
    "www.example.com/img1.png",
    "www.example.com/img1.png",
    "www.example.com/img1.png",
    "www.example.com/img1.pngg",
    "www.example.com/img1.png"
  ],
  "related_articles":[
    {
      "id": "12346",
      "title": "titletitle",
      "image_name": "www.example.com/img1.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "12347",
      "title": "titletitle",
      "image_name": "www.example.com/img2.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm putting this JSON into array like this:

```
data = whole JSON file, which I get from web service
JSONObject jRealObject = new JSONObject(data);

title = jRealObject.getString("title").toString();
text = jRealObject.getString("fulltext").toString();

JSONArray jArray = jRealObject.getJSONArray("gallery");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    gallery.add(jArray.getString(i));
}   

JSONArray jArray = jRealObject.getJSONArray("related_articles");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    relatedId[i] = jRealObject.getString("id").toString();
    relatedTitle[i] = jRealObject.getString("title").toString();
    relatedImage[i] = jRealObject.getString("image_name").toString();
}
```

So when I get JSON with gallery it works perfect, but when article don't have gallery, I get exception:

```
W/System.err(30635): org.json.JSONException: No value for gallery
```

How can I check, if there is "gallery" in JSON ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if an object exists in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049415/check-if-an-object-exists-in-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JSONArray jArray = jRealObject.optJSONArray("gallery",null);

if(jArray != null)

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        gallery.add(jArray.getString(i));
    }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but you don't need to add null, only:
JSONArray jArray = jRealObject.optJSONArray("gallery");

Comment: yaa thats optional :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**GSON**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, this library is a json parse to objects and is very **powerfull**.

Here You have example for you can implemented this library with you json response.

- [Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)
- [GSON tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)