# Why my Android app crashes on sending JSON Object to another activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send JSON string to my second activity onButtonClick, but once I'm doing it my app crashes, when i'm removing: `startNewActivity.putExtra("jsondata", str);`  line it works well, why is that? and how can i solve it?

```
    public void onButtonClick(View view){
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    try {
        String str = obj.toString();
        startNewActivity.putExtra("jsondata", str);
        startActivity(startNewActivity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here's the log:

```
03-09 12:29:27.325 23927-24014/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6310K, 28% free 18043K/24972K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
03-09 12:29:27.965 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1976K, 28% free 18115K/24972K, paused 12ms, total 13ms03-09 12:29:29.855 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 642K, 22% free 19520K/24972K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-09 12:29:31.805 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 666K, 17% free 20902K/24972K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
03-09 12:29:31.825 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 886 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-09 12:29:31.895 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.02
                                                                           Build Date: 01/20/14 Mon
                                                                           Local Branch: PMH2-KK_3.5-RB1-AU61-554722-586267-set2
                                                                           Remote Branch: 
                                                                           Local Patches: 
                                                                           Reconstruct Branch: 
03-09 12:29:31.915 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-09 12:29:32.195 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42838680 time:11069000
03-09 12:29:40.745 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
03-09 12:29:40.785 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
03-09 12:29:44.605 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1099K, 15% free 21445K/24972K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
03-09 12:29:46.805 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1187K, 12% free 22002K/24972K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
03-09 12:30:08.835 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1660K, 12% free 22056K/24972K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
03-09 12:30:12.705 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 848K, 11% free 22416K/24972K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
03-09 12:30:13.795 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 679K, 9% free 22739K/24972K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
03-09 12:30:13.805 23927-23927/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.elinaim.myapplication time:11110611
03-09 12:56:25.825 3576-3576/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 892 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

After this my app crashes with no additional info...
I'm almost positive that its because the size of the JSON string

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: log message: be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: @Eli this is not the crash log. Find the stacktrace of crash and post that.

Comment: that is not what is required, provide log when your app crash.

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help without a logcat print out. How big is the JSON your passing through?

Comment: Sorry to say again but this is not it. Have you set any filter in logcat? That might be causing crash stack trace not to display.

Comment: you log is suppose to contain something like `E/AndroidRuntime(2004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: What's with the downvotes? User is clearly a newbie.

Comment: This is the full log cat, is there anywhere else i should be looking for crashes?

Comment: mention the activity name in the manifest! also get data in getSerializableExtra

Comment: @Sayyaf, i dont think its related because when i'm commenting just those 2 lines startNewActivity.putExtra("jsondata", str);, i'm being passed to the new activity with no problems

Comment: are you passing intent value from any other activity to the destination activity? and may i know how you getting the intent value?

Comment: @Sayyaf, no, i have only 2 activities at the moment

Comment: @Eli can i see your code? or line where the error is occurring at log cat?

Comment: @Sayyaf i'v posted the logcat, this is the last line that i'm getting:

03-09 12:56:25.825 3576-3576/com.example.elinaim.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 892 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105797/discussion-between-sayyaf-and-eli).

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code :

**Activity 1:**

```
     Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                try {
                     String str = obj.toString();
                     //json.isNull( "field-name" ).
                    //String str = "IcebreakerSandy";
                    startNewActivity.putExtra("jsondata", str);
                    startActivity(startNewActivity);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Activity 2:**

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value;
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("jsondata");
        Log.e("Data","is: "+value);
    }
```

**OR** else you can use this simple method to check JSNO object is null or not.

Return the value mapped by the given key, or `{@code null}` if not present or  null.

```
public static String optString(JSONObject json, String key)
{
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13830
    if (json.isNull(key))
        return null;
    else
        return json.optString(key, null);
}
```

**also**  check this Answer by @Jacob Phillips, **Check if an object exist in json** [Check if an object exists in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049415/check-if-an-object-exists-in-json)

If it helps you please vote up.

Comment: Thanks, but i'v checked, the string is not null

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `null` value of `String`.

```
try {
     String str = obj.toString();
     if(str!=null){
      startNewActivity.putExtra("jsondata", str);
     }
     startActivity(startNewActivity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In **Activity2** onCreate():

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("jsondata")){
   String hasValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("jsondata");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but the string is not null. i'v added the full logcat above